# Holomorphic sections of tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm making a stupid mistake but I can't figure out what.  Let $E,F$ be holomorphic vector bundles over a complex manifold $X$.  Let $\mathcal O(E), \mathcal O(F)$ be the respective sheafs of holomorphic sections.  Then isn't it true that $\mathcal O(E\otimes F) \simeq \mathcal O(E)\otimes\mathcal O(F)$, so that the space $h^0(E\otimes F)$ of holomorphic sections of $E\otimes F$ is $h^0(E)h^0(F)$.  But this is not true (e.g. on $\mathbb P^1$, $h^0(\mathcal O(1)) = 2$ byt $h^0(\mathcal O(2)) = 3$).

Thanks.

EDIT

I think my problem is that the presheaf $U \to \mathcal O(E)(U) \otimes \mathcal O(F)(U)$ is not a sheaf, so the tensor product of sheaves is the sheafification of this presheaf.  So it may not be the case that $\mathcal O(E\otimes F)(X) = \mathcal O(E)(X)\otimes\mathcal O(F)(X)$.  But it is true that $\mathcal O(E\otimes F) \simeq \mathcal O(E)\otimes\mathcal O(F)$, right? (with the right side being the sheaf tensor product).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. You have an obvious morphism from the presheaf $U\to\mathcal O(E)(U) \otimes \mathcal O(F)(U)$ to the sheaf $\mathcal O(E \otimes F)$, and, when you pass to the sheafification, this becomes an isomorphism: you can check it on stalks.